# How to define Alias name for Spark Temp Table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to define Alias for Spark temp table ?

```
df.registerTempTable("people".alias("US_People"))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: people is already an alias for df dataframe. why do you want extra name?

Comment: I agree with @RameshMaharjan. You can register it twice if you want but it still doesn't make any sense.